# What is the use of pom.xml file in Java?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

What is the main feature of a POM file and why is it actually used?

How will the dependencies get mapped to the Java virtual machine whatever we give in it and become flexible on application?

Comment: actually i am new to maven please share the information if you have but don't down vote it i am in learners stage

Comment: What would you expect from porn.xml file (pun intended)?

Comment: What do you mean by *"become flexible on application"*?

Comment: @Stefan Beike, there are few things that make me more angry than googling something and seeing the first comment: "Just google [it]"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in
>   Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project
>   and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. It
>   contains default values for most projects. Examples for this is the
>   build directory, which is target; the source directory, which is
>   src/main/java; the test source directory, which is src/main/test; and
>   so on.
>
> The POM was renamed from project.xml in Maven 1 to pom.xml in Maven 2.
>   Instead of having a maven.xml file that contains the goals that can be
>   executed, the goals or plugins are now configured in the pom.xml. When
>   executing a task or goal, Maven looks for the POM in the current
>   directory. It reads the POM, gets the needed configuration
>   information, then executes the goal.

Source: [**Official Documentation**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#What_is_a_POM)

Comment: Now I know what pom stands for!!!

Answer (score 14):

It is not a `java` file. It is `maven` configuration file.

What is a POM?

A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project. [Read more](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).